# $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{3+ 2 \sin (x)}{4+5x \sin(x)} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A friend asked me to compute the following limit:

> **Problem**: Compute: $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{3+ 2 \sin(x)}{4+5 x \sin (x)}$$

I was clueless at first, so I gave it some thought and considered by its graph that the limit does not exist. I thought that the best way to show this would be to consider two convergent sequences and show that for the two of them, the limit produces different outcomes.

I am now curious if my argumentation is correct or if I have made some fallacies during the process.

**Step 1**: Set $x:= \frac{1}{k}, \ \forall k \geq 1$ such that $k \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ which leads to $$\lim_{k \to 0} \frac{3+ 2 \sin\left( \frac{1}{k} \right)}{4+5/k \sin \left( \frac{1}{k} \right)} $$
**Step 2**: Set $ k:= \frac{1}{2 \pi n} \forall n \geq 1$ such that $k \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. See Comment (*) $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3 + 2 \sin (2 \pi n)}{4+ 10 \pi n \sin (2 \pi n)}= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3+0}{4+10 \pi n \cdot 0}= \frac{3}{4}$$
I am not sure about this precise step, because one could argue that $\infty \times 0$ is an indeterminate form in the denominator. Although my thought was that I do the calculation $10 \pi n \times 0=0$ in $\mathbb{N}$

**Step 3**: Set $k:= \displaystyle \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+ 2 \pi n}$ such that again $k \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$ which would lead to $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3 + 2 \sin (\frac{\pi}{2}+2 \pi n)}{4+5(\frac{\pi}{2}+2 \pi n) \sin ( \frac{\pi}{2}+ 2 \pi n)}= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{5}{4+5( \frac{\pi}{2}+ 2 \pi n)}=0 $$

Which would produce evident different results.

**Comment** (*): I believe Step 2 (and therefore step 3) are '**illegal**' because I use two substitutions to arrive at my desired sequence. One could make one substitution $x_n= 2 \pi n$ but this sequence would no longer be convergent. So what I did  was taking one step extra, but I believe that the rigorous argumentation would be now that I have a sequence that depends on $k$ and on $n$

Also I am not sure if at step 2 my result would be correct, did I ignore a possible indeterminate form?

Comment: In the step 1. $\forall k \geq 1$ such that $k \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ first the $\forall k \geq 1$ is wrong and the limit should be $0+$ because in $0-$ is $-\infty$

Comment: The answer is clearly $0$.

Comment: @V-Moy, if the answer appears to be so clear, one should be able to describe it in few less words, right?

Comment: I agree @rlartiga, the $\forall$ quantor makes the statement wrong, I don't see how a $0^+$ in the limit would change things though.

Comment: Because if $x=1/k$ when $k$ tends to $0-$ $x$ tends to $-\infty$

Comment: \begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{3+ 2 \sin x}{4+5 x \sin x}&=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2 \sin x+3}{5 x \sin x+4}\\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\cfrac{2 \sin x}{5 x \sin x}+\cfrac{3}{5 x \sin x}}{\cfrac{5x \sin x}{5 x \sin x}+\cfrac{4}{5 x \sin x}}\\
&=\frac{0+0}{1+0}\\
&=0
\end{align}
As $x\to\infty$, $\sin x$  is finite.

Comment: @Spaced: There were a few unnecessary steps, including the introduction of $k$. But the basic idea is right. When $x=2n\pi$, our function has value $3/4$, while if $x=\pi/2+2n\pi$, where $n$ is large, then our function has value near $0$. Thus the limit does not exist.

Comment: Sorry Folks, but I cannot follow anymore. If my approach (besides having some redundant steps and flawed notation) is in it's core right, how can my method be right and the limit still be equal to zero? My sole intention was to show that it does not exist.

Comment: Prof. @AndréNicolas, how come if $x=2n\pi$ the limit is $\cfrac{3}{4}$??

Comment: I didn't say limit, I said value. For these values of $x$, we have $\sin x=0$, and therefore $x\sin x=0$. Your calculation a few comments ago breaks down for these $x$. Actually, it is not only **at** $2n\pi$ that things break down, a more subtle analysis shows one can find sequences $x_n$ such that the limit of $f(x_n)$ is other than $0$ or $3/4$. But we already have enough to show limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the intuition behind that is very well.
But I think the substitution to zero is not necessary. One should proof that two divergent succesions ("convergent" to infinity) have different limit.

First take $X_k=2k\pi$:

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{3+ 2 \sin(2k\pi)}{4+5 (2k\pi) \sin (2k\pi)}=\frac{3}{4}$$

Second take $X_k=2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$:

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{3+ 2 \sin(2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})}{4+5 (2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}) \sin (2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})}=\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{3+ 2}{4+5 (2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}) }=0$$

Comment: The first one is not $\cfrac{3}{4}$ but $0$.

Comment: $\sin(2k\pi)=0 \ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: But $\infty$ is not even a number.

Comment: One not take the value when $k=\infty$, we calculate the value at which the function is approaching when $k$ is "big"

Comment: Even if $\sin(2k\pi)=0$ but $k\to\infty$ yields an indeterminate form $\infty\cdot0$.

Comment: (Previous comment deleted because @AndréNicolas already cleared my doubts). The notion of ''convergent'' to infinity confused me at first, but it seems to make sense now to check for two divergent successions. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @V-Moy: Your notion of indeterminate form is not correct, it would be better not to use it.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm confused Sir. I don't still get it. (╥﹏╥)

Comment: You surely see that at $x=2n\pi$, or indeed $n\pi$,  our function has value exactly $3/4$.  Similarly, to be fancier, if $x$ is large and on the hyperbola $y=3/x$, our function is very close to $3/7$. We can in fact find a sequence $x_n$ such that the limit of $f(x_n)$ is anything we like.